# Sorting ArrayList by LocalDate with custom Comparator

Tags: java, list, sorting, dictionary, collections

I deserialize some Json and put it into a model with the following structure:

**Model:**

```
import java.time.LocalDate;

public class MyClass implements Serializable {

    String name;
    LocalDate date;
    // more attributes

    public MyClass(...) {
        // ...        
    }

    // getters & setters
}
```

I then put that class into an ArrayList: `List<MyClass> list = new ArrayList<>()`.
The list looks as follows:

```
[
  {
    "name": "peter",
    "date": {
      "year": "1984",
      "month": "10",
      "day": "17"
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "steve",
    "date": {
      "year": "1976",
      "month": "05",
      "day": "04"
    }
  }
]
```

I now want to sort `list` by date, so that `Steve` comes before `Peter`.

---

My approach is:

```
Comparator<Map<String, String>> mapComparator = (Map<String, String> m1, Map<String, String> m2) -> m1.get("date").compareTo(m2.get("date"));
Collections.sort(list, mapComparator);
```

But it says:

```
Not suitable method found for sort(List<MyClass>,Comparator<Map<String,String>>)
```

*Please note, that `date` is of type `LocalDate`, so the "object-structure" of `date` in the ArrayList is made by Java automatically.*

Comment: Are you comparing objects or json strings? Hint, one should be easier than the other.

Comment: It's unclear why you suddenly use `Map<String, String>`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your comparator compares `Map`s. Your list is not a list of `Map`s.

```
list.sort(Comparator.comparing(MyClass::getDate));
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're using map instead of MyClass comparator. Here is the solution:

```
Comparator<MyClass> mapComparator = (MyClass m1, MyClass m2) -> m1.getDate().compareTo(m2.getDate());
Collections.sort(list, mapComparator);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do in this way, using `compareTo`

```
Collections.sort(list, (a,b)->a.getDate().compareTo(b.getDate()));
```